# php explode and calculating the sum of strings

Tags: php

i have an array in my db

```
example : 1:11 1,12 2,13 3,14 4,15 5,16
```

i don't need `1:11` in the array 
and i don't need the `(12,13,14,15,16)`

i just need to explode them and get only 1,2,3,4,5 in the array 
and then i need to calculate the sum of them

```
$tr_arr = $this->data['troops_intrap_num']; // this is the above array from db
$explode_arr = explode(" ", $tr_arr); // exploding the array
print_r($explode_arr); // this will print the array and it should look like this
Aray
(
 [0] => 1:11
 [1] => 1,12
 [2] => 2,13
 [3] => 3,14
 [4] => 4,15
 [5] => 5,16
 [6] => 0
)
```

i need to make something like that after exploding

`Aray
    (
     [0] => 1
     [1] => 2
     [2] => 3
     [3] => 4
     [4] => 5
    )
// and then i need to calculate the sum of the numbers 1+2+3+4+5 = 15 and echo it as 15`

the question is what should i do to remove the first string `1:11` and the last one witch is `0` and then remove the `(12-13-14-15-16)`
so the 1,2,3,4,5 only will be left and then i wan't to calculate the sum of the them

help me

Comment: ... What? You want to calculate the sum of zeroes? Which will be 0?

Comment: you want to find total no of values in which zero exist?

Comment: Do you mean the `count()` of zeroes?

Comment: Are you being coy? I assume the zeroes are not actually zeroes in what you are really trying to do, Right? Otherwise this seems like a fruitless exercise

Comment: zero might be 1 or 2 or even 5000 for each id 12,13,14,15 etcc are only id's of troops number i need

Comment: It really is a bad idea to use unnormalized data in a database; this would be really easy if you structured your data tables sensibly

Comment: i am just working on the project so please help me i edit it to make it better

Comment: i edit the above code please check again to see what i want the result to be

Comment: and note : that 1 2 3 4 5 might be 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000

Comment: Assuming that those values will always be integers: `$total = array_sum(array_map(function ($value) { return (strpos($value, ':') !== false) ? 0 : (int) $value; }, explode(' ', $string)));`

Answer (score 2):

You could simply unset the first value using `unset()`. The last one can be done in the same manner but this isn't neccasary since `array_sum()` will simply add zero.

```
$array = array(
    '1:14:aaaa',
    '1.5',
    '3',
    '4.5',
    '1.5',
    '0',
);

// Unset the first value
unset($array[0]);

// Calculate total amount
$total = array_sum($array);
```

#### Edit

Because your array has numbers with a comma as decimal character, you will first need to convert each value.

```
$array = array_map(function($val) {
    // Without removing decimals
    // return floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $val)));

    // Remove decimals as well
    return floor(floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $val))));
}, $array);
```

#### Complete answer

```
$array = array(
    '1:11',
    '2,12',
    '3,13',
    '4,14',
    '5,15',
    '0',
);

// Unset the first value
unset($array[0]);

$array = array_map(function($val) {
    // Remove decimals as well
    return floor(floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $val))));
}, $array);

// Calculate total amount
$total = array_sum($array);
```

Comment: yes its not what i want i need to get intgers only and sum them

Comment: please make an example to meet what i want

Answer (score 1):

You can make a blacklist array, and check wether the value is contained in that array. If not, add it up to a variable:

```
<?php
// The values you don't want.
$blacklist = array( "1:11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16" );
$tr_arr = $this->data['troops_intrap_num']; // this is the above array from db
$explode_arr = explode(" ", $tr_arr); // exploding the array

$array_sum = 0;

foreach( $explode_arr as $index => $value )
{
    if( !in_array($value, $blacklist) )
    {
        $value = str_replace(",",".", str_replace(".","",$value) );
        $array_sum += floatval($value);
    }
}

print "the sum of the array is: " . $array_sum;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what you want exactly, but here's what I would do. It's a little more complicated to settle for a larger variety of array values so you can use it even if you change it a little.

**I'd do a foreach loop of the array, ignore invalid values (the string and the zero), take the valid values, get the whole number preceding the comma and then add it to the sum.**

Of course there are easier and shorter variants for this, but I'm not sure how much your code would vary.

```
$tr_arr = $this->data['troops_intrap_num']; // this is the above array from db
$explode_arr = explode(" ", $tr_arr); // exploding the array

$sum = 0;
foreach($explode_arr as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 0 OR !is_numeric($value)) {
        // omit the first string, OR alternately omit all not-numbers (not sure if you need to remove the first one specificaly)
        continue;
    }
    if(!$value) {
        // omit the zero at the end
        continue;
    }
    $number = (int)substr($value, 0, strpos($value, ','));

    $sum = $sum + $number;
}
echo $sum;
```

**$sum** will be what you are looking for, if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to tally all of the values that precede a comma while iterating.  `strstr()` with a third parameter of `true` will extract the substring before the needle (and return false if there is no needle).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jO9kL))

```
$array = array(
    '1:11',
    '1,12',
    '2,13',
    '3,14',
    '4,15',
    '5,16',
    '0',
);

$total = 0;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $total += (int)strstr($value, ',', true);
}
echo $total;   // 15
```